# Given a directed graph with 3 nodes, where order of nodes does not matter, how many graphs are possible?

Tags: directed-graphs

No nodes have self referencing arrows.

I tried solving on paper and got 14 graphs.

2 with 2 arrows, 4 with 3 arrows, 5 with 4 arrows, and 2 with 5 arrows, and 1 with 6 arrows.

With 2 arrows: 1 points to 2 points to 3. 1 points to 2 and 3.

With 3 arrows: 1 points to 2 and 3, and 2 points to 3. 1 points to 2 points to 3 points to 2. 1 points to 2 points to 3 points to 1.

With 4 arrows: 1 points to 3 points to 1 points to 2 points to 3. 1 points to 2 points to 1 points to 3, 2 points to 3. 1 points to 2 points to 3 points to 2, 1 points to 3. 1 points to 2 points to 3 points to 2, 3 points to 1. 1 points to 2 points to 3 points to 2 points to 1.

With 5 arrows: 1 points to 2 points to 3 points to 1 points 3, 2 points to 1. 1 points to 2 points to 3 points to 1 points to 3, 2 points to 3.

With 6 arrows: 1, 2, and 3 all point at each other.

Is this right? If not, is there a good source for finding the answer?

And finally, is there a textbook or source that goes into this? I tried looking for one, but the free graph theory textbooks I found don't cover this.

Comment: Please draw your graphs... particularly the ones with five arrows.

Comment: -1 bota "dnm" itt.

Comment: I'll have to wait until I get a better internet connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the graphs:

With zero edges:

[image]

With one edge:

[image]

With two edges:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

With three edges:

[image]

[image]
Done!

Comment: I meant with arrows that can go backwards too

Comment: Based on what you wrote though, I appear to have them all. Thank you for your help!